# Javascript Code For Firefox Console.log To Delete All Discord Messages I Sent In Dms

Tags: javascript

im using this persons sourse code I found on github. So I can delete the messages I sent to particular users on discord.

```
var before = 'LAST_MESSAGE_ID';

clearMessages = function(){
    
    const channel = window.location.href.split('/').pop();
    
    const baseURL = https://discordapp.com/api/channels/${channel}/messages;
    
    const headers = {"Authorization": "YOUR TOKEN HIER" };

    let clock = 0;
    
    let interval = 500;

    function delay(duration) {
        
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            
            setTimeout(() => resolve(), duration);
        });
    }

    fetch(baseURL + '?before=' + before + '&limit=100', {headers})
        
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        
        .then(messages => {
        
         return Promise.all(messages.map((message) => {
            
             = message.id;
            
             return delay(clock += interval).then(() => fetch(${baseURL}/${message.id}, {headers, method:  

     'DELETE'}));
        }));
    
        }).then(() => clearMessages());
}
clearMessages();
```

But when i put my userId and discord authorization token in the code and pasted it into console.log on firefox i get this error

```
Source map error: Error: request failed with status 403 Resource URL: https://discord.com/assets/40532.476e4293de2fc7733cf0.css Source Map URL: 40532.476e4293de2fc7733cf0.css.map

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: messages.map is not a function clearMessages debugger eval code:19 promise callbackclearMessages debugger eval code:18 clearMessages debugger eval code:23 promise callbackclearMessages debugger eval code:23 clearMessages debugger eval code:23 promise callbackclearMessages debugger eval code:23 clearMessages debugger eval code:23 promise callbackclearMessages debugger eval code:23 clearMessages debugger eval code:23
```

I tried looking this up and trying to understand this please note i know nothing about javascript i am barely of somewhat knowleage in HTML and CSS

so i realize at least that map im guessing like css is the actual command "fuction" but it needs to know what map = to im guessing?

any help would be a universe send!

I was expecting for all my messages on a certain discord dm to be deleted after i pasted this javascript code into the console.log of firefox inspect manager aka dev tools

Comment: Don’t paste code you don’t understand into the console.   ESPECIALLY don’t put your auth tokens into code you don’t understand in the console.

Comment: What do you recommened if i want to be able to mass delete all my discord messages i sent?

Answer (score 1):

## This giant warning is shown in the Chrome console when logged in on Discord website:

> ### Hold Up!
>
> If someone told you to copy/paste something here you have an 11/10 chance you're being scammed.
> **Pasting anything in here could give attackers access to your Discord account.**

[image: Extra large, colored font warning shown when opening the Chrome developer tools while logged into Discord on the browser]

---

If you want to go about this correctly, read the Discord API documentation:

- [Developer Portal homepage](https://discord.com/developers/applications).
- [Gateway API documentation for `Message Delete` command](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway-events#message-delete)

There is a Gateway API for [`Message Bulk Delete`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway-events#message-delete) but this page states: ["This endpoint can only be used on guild channels"](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#bulk-delete-messages). It notably [doesn't say that for `Message Delete`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#delete-message).

Luckily, you've got some syntax errors in your code that are preventing you from hitting the target URL correctly.

Be safe out there.

Comment: But wait that doesnt allow mass delete on dms does it thou?

Comment: @user21491324 My guess is that a DM just has a "channel ID" that would be used for the API. I'm not 100% sure, but when I was poking around their docs for you, I couldn't find anything on DMs specifically.